# ArrayList parameter doesn't update during recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I thought that when an ArrayList is passed as a parameter and is updated during recursion, the ArrayList gets modified in all recursion stack frames. Is that incorrect?

I'm trying to pass an empty ArrayList and then fill it with permutations of a word. I understand that I don't have to pass an empty ArrayList as a parameter and could instead return an ArrayList from this method, but I'm wondering whether my understanding of how objects are stored and updated during recursion is incorrect.

```
public static void findPermutations(String str, ArrayList<String> l, int from, int to, StringBuilder sb){

    if(from+1 == to){
      l.add(""+str.charAt(from));
      return;
    }

    if(from+2 == to){
      l.add(""+str.charAt(from)+str.charAt(from+1));
      l.add(""+str.charAt(from+1)+str.charAt(from));
      return;
    }

    char curr = str.charAt(from);
    findPermutations(str,l,from+1,to,sb);

    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String s: l){      
      for(int i=0; i<=s.length(); i++){
        sb.append(s.substring(0,i));
        sb.append(curr);
        sb.append(s.substring(i));
        newList.add(sb.toString());
        sb.setLength(0);
      }
    }

    //Making a copy of the arraylist
    //Shouldn't it update in the other recursion call stacks as well?

    l=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s:newList){
      l.add(s);
    }
  }
```

Comment: why are you initializing `l` in the method?

Comment: If we have "abcd", after the base case runs, ArrayList l contains "cd" and "dc". I then add b to every position in each of the strings and overwrite the l array by making it refer to a new Arraylist and then putting strings from the newList into it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the list is passed in by reference, `l`only refers to the reference.  When you do `l=new ArrayList<>()` you are simply updating `l`to point to a new instance.  The original list is unaffected and the `l`s further down in the recursion stack are still referencing the original list.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Making a copy of the arraylist
//Shouldn't it update in the other recursion call stacks as well?

l.clear(); // Do you really want to do this? 
           // It is analogous to the l = new ArrayList<>(), 
           // but it throws away the previous work.
l.addAll(newList);
```

That change updates all the variables that contain a reference to l throughout the recursion.